# Using normalize-space with XPath to Remove Whitespaces

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath

I'm dealing with the following HTML layout on hundreds of pages, which I want to scrape data from:

```
<div class="store stores_show cms_page_text">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col_4 m_col_8 stores_list_address">
          <p class="store_header">
    Russell & Bromley                       
          </p>
    Unit 3A
         <br/>  
    35-38 George Street<br/>
                TW9 1HY                                     
      </div>
      <div class="col col_4 m_col_8 stores_list_contact">
      <strong>T.</strong>         02089486805<br/>                                                          </div>
```

The following XPath will extract 'Russell & Bromley', but it also extracts whitespace characters which I do not want:

> //*[@id="stores_list"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/p

How could I use the normalize-space function with the above XPath to remove whitespace?

Microsoft supporting document:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256063(v=vs.110).aspx

Example Strings:

> normalize-space(" abc def ")

```
<xsl:template match="/text">
Unnormalized: 
"<xsl:value-of select='.'/>"
Normalized: "<xsl:value-of select='normalize-space()'/>"
</xsl:template>
```

I can't get this to to work my own XPath, any ideas?

Please let me know if you require more information. I want to avoid a second-step such as eliminating whitespace characters via Excel.

Many thanks in advance, totally over my head with this as a newb with 0 experience.

Comment: please publish your HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Extract the value by using with your xpath.
2. Save the value in a string.
3. Use the normalize-space function to remove the leading and trailing white spaces

Comment: Thanks for your input, Jaya; unfortunately this does not seem like a suitable solution for me as I'll be extracting the same information from thousands of pages regularly - which is why I'd like to automate this as much as possible in the extraction stage (instead of needing a second step such as using Excel's TRIM function or the steps you suggested)

Comment: I have seen something about normalize-space and translate function in the documentation https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space. Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like it's on the right track but I can't get it to work with my own XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
normalize-space(//*[@id="stores_list"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/p)
```

Comment: Hey Stephan, thanks for your response; I tried your suggestion but sadly it did not work - none of the text was extracted. Do you have any idea what's missing? I've tried a few variations of the above XPath and can't seem to get it to work even slightly.

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.